# Rails form not submitting

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to make a Rails form, and unfortunately it will not submit. I believe this to be due to the error I'm getting when I try to display "index.html.erb", which is this:

```
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"recipes", :method=>"get"}, missing required keys: [:id]
```

View:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Recipe List</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Recipes</h1>
    <%= form_tag recipe_path :method => 'get' do %>
    <%= search_field_tag :search, params[:search], placeholder: "Search recipes" %>
    <%= submit_tag "Search" %>
    <% end %>

<% if @recipe.present? %>
  <%= render @recipe %>
<% else %>
  <p>There are no recipes containing the term(s) <%= params[:search] %>.</p>
<% end %>

    <% @recipes.each do |s| %>
    <span class="name"><%= s.name %></span>
    <p><%= s.scam %></p>
    <% end %>
</body>
</html>
```

Controller:

```
class RecipeController < ApplicationController

  def index
    recipe_path = '/recipe'
  @recipe = Recipe.all
  if params[:search]
    @recipe = Recipe.search(params[:search]).order("created_at DESC")
  else
    @recipe = Recipe.all.order('created_at DESC')
  end
 end

end
```

Model:

```
class Recipe < ApplicationRecord

    def self.search(search)
            where("name LIKE", "%#{search}%")
    end
end
```

Routes file:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  resources :recipes
  get 'recipe' => 'recipe#index'
   # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow.

I see several issues. But, the one that's blocking you is in the routes file. `resources :recipes` declares several routes for you, including `/recipes/:id` which is referenced as `recipes_path`. That's the route you're using in your form. Therefore, your form requires the `:id` parameter. Thus, the error you're seeing.

Comment: What are the rest (I'm new to Rails)?

Comment: I don't mean to be rude. But, StackOverflow is a site for specific programming questions. Best I can do is to recommend that you spend some time with the Rails documentation, read a book, and/or use the built-in Rails scaffold generator, to see how controllers and views should work together. `rails generate scaffold Class field1:string field2:text field3:datetime field4:integer`